# Compactification of Swift Generic Collection where constraint

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I have a function that operates on generic collections:

```
func foo<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ bar: T) 
     where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8
{
    //
}
```

The function then accesses subranges of that collection, so it needs additional constraints:

```
func foo<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ bar: T) 
     where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
           T.SubSequence: RangeReplaceableCollection,
           T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element
{
    //
}
```

It also calls functions that themselves operate on subranges of the subranges of the collection, so it needs even more constraints:

```
func foo<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ bar: T) 
     where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
           T.SubSequence: RangeReplaceableCollection,
           T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element,
           T.SubSequence.SubSequence: RangeReplaceableCollection,
           T.SubSequence.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == 
               T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element
{
    //
}
```

- Is there any way how this can be cleaned up?
- Is there at least a way to hide all those where clauses behind a `typealias`?
- If not, is there a proposal that addresses this issue?

Comment: Why is there `AnyRandomAccessCollection<T>` but no `AnyRangeReplaceableCollection<T>`? Would also solve the issue and getting rid of all clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collections subsequence need not have the same type as the collection
itself, but – as far as I know – the subsequence of a subsequence has
the same type as the subsequence itself for all collections defined
in the standard library. Therefore one additional constraint

```
    T.SubSequence.SubSequence == T.SubSequence
```

should solve your problem for arbitrarily nested subsequences:

```
func foo<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ bar: T)
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
    T.SubSequence: RangeReplaceableCollection,
    T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element,
    T.SubSequence.SubSequence == T.SubSequence
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Any chance for a typealias in case I want to have the same constraints on multiple functions?